# How to proceed with benefits reimbursement?

Tags: management, resignation, human-resources, contracts, company-policy

In my company, as an employee, I received "benefits" like 25% discount for studying for a master's degree in their university, and for being paid full time for 6 months while doing the corresponding master research thesis in another country. But now that I have expressed my resignation less than 2 years of such events, HR doesn't have a clear answer as to what to do and are going to escalate the case since they made me sign a contract saying that I would reimburse the "benefits" in not staying to work with them for 4 years after finishing the study. What do you recommend I should do/say?

Disclaimer: I'm was younger and I acknowledge that shouldn't have signed such contracts. This is the defacto practice in this HR department but in all other cases, the employees have remained over 4 years and seemingly forever since they have managerial positions unlike me who is trying to improve my financial condition elsewhere.

Comment: Get a copy of the contract and show it to a lawyer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no, I just expressed directly to HR

Comment: You might as well apply the same logic in all sites: want advice? seek "professional" help outside (because here there are none), one also learn from specific cases,  for general questions there are books or only-read websites

Answer (score 6):

> What do you recommend I should do/say?

Do nothing for now.

If/when HR asks you to pay back some or all of the cost of your benefits due to breaking your contract, you can either just pay it or talk to your lawyer and see if there is an alternative.

Then, if you haven't saved the money required, ask about a repayment plan.

In my experience, these contract clauses are binding. A company could choose to enforce them, or could choose to just ignore them. You should always be prepared to pay if you violate the terms of your contract.